# Need to get the Timezone details

Tags: linux, time, timezone

I was in the process of getting the time zone details from the some of the machine in the infrastructure.

And some machines have `timedatectl` and getting the required details seems to be quite easy from this.

```
$/etc/bin/timedatectl | /bin/grep "Timezone"
  Timezone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -8000)
```

But I was looking for alternative was to get the time zone details in the machines which does not have `timedatectl` command in them.

And ended up checking the /etc/locatime file and since this is a binary file. Hence finding some hard time in getting the required details.

Answer (score 3):

```
date +%Z
```

That will give you the time zone. eg GMT,PST...etc

The date command by itself also includes this information.

see `man date` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since `/etc/localtime` is usually* a symlink to a file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`, you should be able to issue `ls -l /etc/localtime` to get the timezone info you need on any linux based machine.

*) unless `/usr` is on a separate drive/partition, then it's a file, making this method less-than-useful. ^_^;

Comment: If your setup has `/usr` as a separate filesystem, then `/etc/localtime` probably won't be a symlink but an actual copy of the appropriate timezone file from `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, as it should be available also during early boot when `/usr` might not be mounted yet.

Comment: I was not aware of that. None of my systems have `/usr` on a separate partition. Thanks for adding that tidbit. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following commands:

```
cat /etc/timezone
```

Sample output:

```
Africa/Tunis
```

Then:

```
zdump Africa/Tunis
```

Sample output:

```
Africa/Tunis  Wed Feb 14 21:09:03 2018 CET
```